# Problems passing parameters through the put method using fetch

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm having problems trying to pass parameters by the put method using fetch

For this I am trying the following

```
fetch(`brands/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({name: 'dummy text'})
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        if (json.status === 'ok') {
            // do some relevant logic

            return false;
        }

        showErrors(json.errors);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error.message));
```

I am also trying using the FormData interface

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', 'some dummy text');

fetch(`brands/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: formData
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        if (json.status === 'ok') {
            // Some relevant logic

            return false;
        }

        showErrors(json.errors);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error.message));
```

But I am getting the same result (name parameter is not in the controller)

Inspected the network tab I can see that ajax has been called and in the params tab I can see that the variables are passed. But when trying to access these parameters from the controller they do not appear.

I appreciate your help

[image]

In backend when printing the parameters received in this query, the name parameter is not listed.

In backend the relevant parts in the controller definition are the following

The update method can only be invoked through the put method

```
static allowedMethods = [
    save: 'POST',
    update: 'PUT'
]
```

Here I hope that the name parameter has a value, but the parameter does not exist

```
def update() {
    try {
        Brand brand = brandService.update(params.id, params.name)

        render(contentType: 'application/json') {
            [status: 'ok', brand: brand]
        }
    } catch(ValidationException e) {
        render(contentType: 'application/json') {
            [status: 'fail', errors: e.errors]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried sending a stringified JSON? The FormData Object can behave unexpected when not iterated over and stored in a new object first.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am trying sending stringifed JSON, I found an example in this mdn post https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_a_file and here an example using formData https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_multiple_files

Comment: do you have any body-parser packages like in nodejs ?

Comment: do you mean something like a middleware? there is nothing that manipulates the request body before the controller

Comment: The example is for uploading a file. Take a look at your formData in the console... I recently struggled with posting form data using fetch and converting it into regular JSON solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running your form through this little helper might do the trick:

```
form2Obj(form) {
    const obj = {};
    new FormData(form).forEach((val, key) => obj[key] = val);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that destroy sending multi-values for a single key (for arrays in the form)?

Comment: Do you mean for a set of radio-inputs? Can you give an example?